# What's the point of instances polymorphic only on type constructors?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
```

In Haskell I can do something like

```
class C a where
  c :: a -> a

instance C (f Integer) where
  c = id
```

As seen, the instance of `C` is polymorphic, but only on the type constructor and not on the type parameter. What is the point of this feature? I have never seen this used, but since it is allowed I assume there is some case where it is useful. Is it?

Comment: The question isn't "what's the point of [allowing this]?" but rather "What would be the point of explicitly *disallowing* it?" Just because something is legal doesn't imply that it has to be *useful*.

Comment: (Which is not to say that it might *not* be useful, only that this is something that falls out from a simple definition of type classes, not something that was specifically targeted as a feature to support.)

Comment: This particular example indeed looks useless, but `instance D f => F (f Integer) where` could be useful, since it could exploit the `D f` context to do some non trivial transformation. Once we allow this, I think it would be weird to forbid the empty-context variant you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've seen it used. Here's some examples:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
and :: Foldable f => f Bool -> Bool
traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

Each of these is polymorphic in a type with arrow kind -- respectively, `m`, `f`, and both `f` and `t`. If you *must* see it in an instance head, it's not hard to lift any of these to an analogous instance. For example:

```
class Bullish a where bull :: a -> Bool
instance Bullish Bool where bull = id
instance Bullish Int where bull = (0/=)
instance Foldable f => Bullish (f Bool) where bull = and
```

As a terminology note: "type constructor" is not actually synonymous with "type with arrow kind", for essentially the same reasons that "data constructor" is not synonymous with "value with arrow type".

```
                   arrow kind    not arrow kind
constructor        Maybe         Bool
not constructor    State Int     Maybe Char
```